# How can I auto Indent for Cobol and JCl using Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, cobol, mainframe, jcl

Any one Please tell me how to autoindent my cobol and JCL codes. It will be easy for me to write programs if i use those intendationi n notepad++. Please reply me.

Comment: Might be a question for people knowing nuts and bolts of notepad++. Try http://superuser.com or http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

Indenting JCL would be counter productive since all commands must start with a "//" in the first two columns.

Notepad++, at least version 5.8.3 and on, claims to have Cobol indention built in.  Check your files and make sure the file extension lines up with what Notepad++ is configures for, usuall ".cbl" or ".cob" to activate auto-indention.